# How to scrape 2 web page with same domain on scrapy using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi guys I am very new in scraping data, I have tried the basic one. But my problem is I have 2 web page with same domain that I need to scrape

My Logic is,
First page `www.sample.com/view-all.html`
  *This page open all the list of items and I need to get all the href attr of every item.

Second page `www.sample.com/productpage.52689.html`

*this is the link came from the first page so 52689 needs to change dynamically depending on the link provided by the first page.

I need to get all the data like title, description etc on the second page.

what I am thinking is for loop but Its not working on my end. I am searching on google but no one has the same problem as mine. please help me

```
import scrapy

class SalesItemSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sales_item'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sample.com']
    start_urls = ['www.sample.com/view-all.html', 'www.sample.com/productpage.00001.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for product_item in response.css('li.product-item'):
            item = {
                'URL': product_item.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(),
            }
            yield item`
```

Comment: Scrapy doesn't have to `yield` item. It can `yield` Request() with url and funtion name which will scrape from this url. This way `parse` can scrape urls from main page and use `Request()` to run other function to scrape from these urls. You shoul have all in documentation - https://docs.scrapy.org/ - If you interested in scraping then you should read this documentation from first page to the last page.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `parse` you can `yield` `Request()` with url and function's name to scrape this url in different function

```
def parse(self, response):

    for product_item in response.css('li.product-item'):
        url = product_item.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first() 

        # it will send `www.sample.com/productpage.52689.html` to `parse_subpage` 
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_subpage)


def parse_subpage(self, response):
    # here you parse from www.sample.com/productpage.52689.html 

    item = {
        'title': ..., 
        'description': ...
    }

    yield item
```

Look for `Request` in [Scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#) and [its tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

---

There is also

```
response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_subpage)
```

which will automatically add `www.sample.com` to urls so you don't have to do it on your own in

```
Request(url = "www.sample.com/" + url, callback=self.parse_subpage)
```

See [A shortcut for creating Requests](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests)

---

If you interested in scraping then you should read [docs.scrapy.org](https://docs.scrapy.org/) from first page to the last one.

Comment: Thank you @furas it's all working I've read the documentation and understand the functions. I've changed some in the code you had provided and now it's working fine thank you